# Python: Numerov's method plotting error

Tags: python, plot

I'm  trying to solve the [Schrödinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_spherically_symmetric_potential#Relationship_with_1-D_Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) with the [Numerov's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerov%27s_method#Application). Here is my code:

```
from pylab import *
from scipy.optimize import brentq
import numpy as np

l = float(input("Angular momentum l:"))
L = float(input("Width of the potential:"))
Vo = float(input("Value of the potential:"))
N = int(input("Number of steps (~10000):"))
h = float(3*L/N)
psi = np.zeros(N) #wave function
psi[0] = 0
psi[1] = h

def V(x,E):
    """
    Effective potential function.
    """
    if x > L:
        return -2*E+l*(l+1)/x**2
    else:
        return -2*(Vo+E)+l*(l+1)/x**2

def Wavefunction(energy):
    """
    Calculates wave function psi for the given value
    of energy E and returns value at point xmax
    """
    global psi
    global E
    E=energy
    for i in range(2,N):
        psi[i]=(2*(1+5*(h**2)*V(i*h,E)/12)*psi[i-1]-(1-(h**2)*V((i-1)*h,E)/12)*psi[i-2])/(1-(h**2)*V((i+1)*h,E)/12)       
    return psi[-1]

def find_energy_levels(x,y):
    """
    Gives all zeroes in y = psi_max, x=en
    """
    zeroes = []
    s = np.sign(y)
    for i in range(len(y)-1):
        if s[i]+s[i+1] == 0: #sign change
            zero = brentq(Wavefunction, x[i], x[i+1])
            zeroes.append(zero)
    return zeroes

def main():

    energies = np.linspace(-Vo,0,int(10*Vo))   # vector of energies where we look for the stable states
    psi_max = []  # vector of wave function at x = 3L for all of the energies in energies
    for energy in energies:
        psi_max.append(Wavefunction(energy))     # for each energy find the the psi_max at xmax
    E_levels = find_energy_levels(energies,psi_max)   # now find the energies where psi_max = 0  
    print ("Energies for the bound states are: ")
    for E in E_levels:
        print ("%.2f" %E)
    # Plot the wavefunctions for first 4 eigenstates
    x = np.linspace(0, 3*L, N)
    figure()
    for E in E_levels:
        Wavefunction(E)
        plot(x, psi, label="E = %.2f"%E)
    legend(loc="upper right")
    xlabel('r')
    ylabel('$u(r)$', fontsize = 10)
    grid()
    savefig('numerov.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Everything was working really well, this is a plot for [Vo=35, l=1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCgso.png), but when I try whit a value of [Vo=85, l=0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8GXr.png) (is the same for Vo>50), the plot is not what I expected (the end of the plot blows up). For [l=1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcdVb.png), the error vanish. I am a novice in Python, so I do not know what would be the error. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Questions to help my own understanding: **1.** What potential widths (`L`) did you use to create these plots? **2.** Why is there a `3` in `h = float(3*L/N)`? As far as I see, this reduces spatial resolution by a factor of 3, same as just reducing `N` or increasing `L` directly. **3.** Why choose `psi[1] = h`? `h` is the spatial step size, so `psi[1]` holds the value of the wavefunction at x = x0 + h, but there's no reason for the value of `psi[1]` to *equal* `h`.

Comment: L=1 for all the cases. The factor of 3 is in there because I want to solve the equation in [0;3L] with the condition psi(3L)=0 (this make sense in quantum mechanics). I can choose any value for psi[1], but I choose this because is recommended in this paper (page 6): https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.7092.pdf . Previously I worked with psi[1]=1 obtaining the same results (the same form of the plot, normalization will come later).